# Custom object change tracking in Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, change-tracking

I need to implement change tracking for state of any object.
How would I implement it?

For example:

```
let complexObject = {
   /// ... mant many arrays and propertiess
}

let hash = convertToHash(complexObject)

let trackingArray = []

trackingArray.push(hash);

/// what from here and how to imlement it?
```

Comment: This question is somewhat vague - what exactly do you mean by change tracking? What is the end goal you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/ when you change something you will get a new object. It will be much more efficient than creating a hash because you will not need to iterate the entire object graph.

Also it shares some memory internally so it will be more efficient than storing full clones in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are implementing change tracking for purpose of undo/redo functionality.

One way is to use immutable objects and store on stack old object each time when there is action invoked.

In order to capture change to objects you could use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern or redux (widely popular in react, [implementation for angular](http://blog.rangle.io/managing-state-redux-angular/)).